# How to go to another page after login? using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to go to another page after login?

this is my current code

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleLogin = async()=>{
     let path = `../userList/Mainpage`; 
     history.push(path);
  }
```

here is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
              <Switch>
                .....
                <Route exact path="/Mainpage" name="Mainpage" render={props => <Mainpage {...props}/>} />

              </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

error i encounter

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

Comment: can you give a clearer version of your code that shows the parent component also whether you are in a protected route or not ?

Comment: this `../userList/Mainpage` I dont want to include it to my routes, is that possible?

Comment: I don't know the scenario but I assume, if it's not in your routes, the user will be redirected to 404 page (if it exits)

Comment: if it is not in the routes than how would it ever navigate to that url?